# Issue With tkinter buttons

Tags: python, tkinter

Currently trying to use tkinter to create a simple login gui and I'm running into an issue with the button. This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from requesting_internet import login


window = Tk()


def login_button_function():
    username = Username_entry.get()
    password = Password_entry.get()
    print(login(username, password))

Login_label = Label(window, text="Login:")
Login_label.grid(row=0, column=1)
Username_label = Label(window, text="Username")
Username_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
Username_entry = Entry(window, bd=5)
Username_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2)
Password_label = Label(window, text="Password")
Password_label.grid(row=2, column=0)
Password_entry = Entry(window, bd=5, show="*")
Password_entry.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=2)
Login_button = Button(window, text="Login")
Login_button.grid(row=3, column=1, command = login_button_function)

window.mainloop()
```

Whenever I run this code I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filename.py", line 30, in <module>
    Login_button.grid(row=3, column=1, command = login_button_function)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2220, in grid_configure
    + self._options(cnf, kw))
_tkinter.TclError: bad option "-command": must be -column, -columnspan, -in, -ipadx, -ipady, -padx, -pady, -row, -rowspan, or -sticky
```

I haven't been able to find anything to fix this problem online anywhere.

Comment: The `command` goes into the `Button` constructor, not into the `grid` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referencing a command argument, an argument used for buttons, inside the grid placement function, which does not have a command argument, move command to when you create the button and it should be fine.

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew it was something obvious and stupid